# How do i display details of a specific vehicle within a queue. The user will enter the reg and this will display that vehicle details

Tags: java, object, queue

```
public boolean contains(String findRegNum) {

    //if empty queue node isnt there
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    VehicleNode ref = start;

    while (ref != null) {
        if (ref.getRegNum().equalsIgnoreCase(findRegNum)) {
            return true;
        }

        ref = ref.getPrevious();
    }//while

    //get to end of queue and node isnt there
    return false;

}//contains

case 6:
    String vReg = "";
    System.out.println("Enter Reg");
    vReg = input.next();
    if (myQ.contains(vReg)) {
        System.out.println(vReg);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Queue doesn't contain this vehicle");
    }

    break;
```

As you can see i have a contains method that loops through the queue. However, in the menu (case 6) i can only work out how to display the reg of the vehicle. I need to be able to enter the registration and display the rest of the vehicle details while will be:

```
VehicleNode newNode = new VehicleNode(reg, vtype, nat, pass, charge, tonnage);
```

I think i might need to use this peice of code below from the vehicleNode class:

```
public String nodeDetails() {
    return "Reg #" + regNum + "Type" + type + "Charge"
            + charge + "Passengers" + passengers + "Tonnage" + tonnage
            + "Nationality" + nationality;
}
```

As you can see i have only been able to display the vehicle reg if it finds the vehicle reg inside the queue, but i need to enter in a reg, if it finds it in the queue, display ALL the details, not just the reg.

I also need to make the reg unique if you have any idea on this also?

Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated!!

Thank you

Comment: why not modify your contains method to find(reg) that return the vehicle if it exists or null otherwise ?

Comment: Need to work on that formatting a bit. Not sure what I'm looking at. Are you required to use a queue? This is a case for a `Map`. `LinkedHashMap` preserves insertion order.
Also, nobody knows what `start` is. You didn't share what your queue actually is.